# Finding orthogonal $\def\R{\Bbb R}T: \R^3 \rightarrow\R^3$ such that $T([2/3,2/3,1/3]) = [0,0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I had a question about orthogonal transformations. Say we wanted an orthogonal transformation $T:\R^3 \rightarrow\R^3$ such that $T([2/3,2/3,1/3]) = [0,0,1]$.

How could this be solved? Thanks

Comment: Do note that you can (and should) put entire mathematical statements between dollar signs, not just the stuff that you need dollar signs to implement.

Comment: I will take note of that, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Complete the normal vector $[2,2,1]/3$ to an orthonormal basis by adding two appropriate vectors. Then map those by $T$ to the remaining two standard basis vectors. For chosen images of each of the orthonormal basis vectors, there is a unique $T$ that will do this, and it will be orthogonal. It is probably easiest to write down $T^{-1}$ first (which equals $T^t$), and then transpose it.

Comment: So would this be a valid basis:  \begin{matrix}
        1 & -1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & -2 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$                                                                                                                    , since if we multiply x with it we get the resultant vector?

Comment: I don't see where you get that matrix from, nor how to interpret it as a basis; certainly its columns are not orthonormal (nor its rows), and it does not contain $[2,2,1]/3$.